# Message data of MSI-X is useless, right?

Tags: pci-e

As we know, Message data in MSI, is used to indicate which vector you are going to trigger.
But, in MSI-X, we have different Message address for different vectors. So, looks like Message data in MSI-X
is Useless.
If it's correct, then why PCIe spec design MSI-X like that?

1: No API in linux kernel to set message data of MSI-X?
2: Host driver can not get the message data, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. MSI-X is a signal direction message from EP to RC, MSI-X message is used for EP only
2. message data is set in function arch_setup_msi_irq(msi.c), but I only found xilinx pcie bridge use message data property, so I think host driver not use message data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
why xilinx pcie bridge need to set the message data?  Does the message data content mean for something?

Answer (score 0):

The message data in MSI-X is used the same way than in MSI, i.e. to generate a write transaction in which the data is set to that value.

The main advantages of MSI-X are:

- you can have up to 1024 interrupts (the maximum in MSI was 32)
- you can trigger different interrupts to different cores/CPUs, given that you can use a different address for each interrupt, thus, you can now have a different destination ID in each one (in MSI you can only interrupt to one destination ID)

However, the last point is less of an advantage in modern systems, because there will usually be a Interrupt Remapping Engine which can map one (address, data) to a different (address, data) and therefore, it is now possible to address different cores/CPUs using the same address configured in the device